# Jersey: Returning 400 error instead of 500 when given invalid request body

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey's integrated Jackson processing to transform incoming JSON to a POJO, e.g.:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response newCustomer( CustomerRepresentation customer)
{
...
}
```

If a client sends JSON with invalid fields Jersey currently returns a `500 Internal Server Error`.  Instead, I'd like to return a `400 Bad Request`, preferably with some meaningful detail indicating which fields are in error.

Any insight into how this could be accomplished?  (At least returning a generic 400 instead of the completely inappropriate 500?)

**Update:**
Here's the exception being generated server-side, before my handler is invoked:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
Unrecognized field "this_isnt_a_known"_field" (Class com.redacted....), not marked as ignorable
```

Comment: `400` actually means `Bad request`, i.e. the server thinks that client has send the wrong request. So semantically it does not fit what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for catching my slip.  I intended to type "Bad Request".  Question edited accordingly.

Comment: Jersey usually returns 400 if the request body is invalid. Are you sure it doesn't fail in the body of your method with a NPE or something? Do you see any error and/or stack trace in your app server logs?

Comment: Thanks!  It's good to know that Jersey is *supposed* to return 400. I'm updating the question to include the server-side exception.  It's definitely being generated is being generated before reaching my handler and is related to an unrecognized field in the JSON.

Comment: @HolySamosa: What you can do is to run your web container in debug mode, put breakpoint when `UnrecognizedPropertyException` is raised and see what happens when it is processed. Perhaps you'll catch a bug in Jersey.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was finally able to work around this problem by implementing an `ExceptionMapper` to catch the `UnrecognizedPropertyException` thrown by Jackson and map it to a 400 Bad Request response:

```
@Provider
public class UnrecognizedPropertyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnrecognizedPropertyException>
{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(UnrecognizedPropertyException exception)
    {
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity( "'" + exception.getUnrecognizedPropertyName() + "' is an unrecognized field.")
                .type( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: @HolySamosa Thanks for sharing this. but somehow `toResponse()` is not getting invoked.

Comment: hey HolySamosa...Can you let us know how is your toResponse() is invoked. I am stuck with this issue and did not have any solution to throw 400 instead of 500 error.

Comment: +1 Because your solution gave me the a tip for troubleshooting. I got the **HTTP 400 Bad request** error with invalid data type in a "multipart/form-data". Catch a general exception helped me to find the issue -> public class ExceptionInterceptor implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>

Answer (score 3):

I tried mapping **status 500** to **status 400** with HolySamosa's answer but the exception was not caught by this mapper, and **status 500** was still being returned.

After debugging I found that **JsonParseException** is being thrown and not **UnrecognizedPropertyException**. This is because I was sending some garbage text (that was not JSON at all).

When I sent a proper JSON from client side, with format that was not appropriate for my DTO on the server side, then I got **UnrecognizedPropertyException**.
So there are two cases for this:

- when you send garbage that is not JSON and
- when you send JSON, but it is not a match for your DTO class.

Now I am returning **status 400** for both.

Answer (score 3):

In dropwizard land there is an `ExceptionMapper` called [JsonProcessingExceptionMapper](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/jackson/JsonProcessingExceptionMapper.java) that has similar functionality as to what you are looking for. Maybe you can use that for inspiration on how to address your specific issue in a non-dropwizard world.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem... Unfortunately, there's no good way that I know of to intercept the Jackson exception and generate your own error code.

One option you have is to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and then strictly validate the deserialized object. This won't tell you if your sender transmitted junk, but if they missed required fields, you'll catch that.

I cannot find any way to access the actual JSON passed in, other than creating an @Provider class to trap the JSON, validate it, then pass it to Jackson for deserialization.

Comment: Jersey can pass the JSON to your handler as a JsonNode which would allow us to validate well formed JSON, but Jersey would still return 500 for a non-JSON request (or so I assume-- I haven't tried yet).

Comment: I finally returned to working on this issue and was able to work around it using an ExceptionMapper.