# Handling Jackson Exception

Tags: java, json, exception, jersey, jackson

i've a Rest built using jersey and i try to handle exceptions.
I registered jackson how default json processor for all operations regarding json mapping using this class:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
   public MyApplication() {
       packages("controller");
       register(JacksonFeature.class);       
   }
}
```

I defined an exception mapper to catch some exceptions like for example "UnauthorizedException" and "BadRequestException" using the following class:

```
@Provider
public class ClientExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BaseException>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BaseException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("qwertweryt");
        if(ex instanceof UnauthorizedException)
        {
            System.out.println("Unauthorized!");
            return (((UnauthorizedException)ex).getResponse());
        }
        else if(ex instanceof BadrequestException)
        {
            System.out.println("Badrequest!");
            return (((BadrequestException)ex).getResponse());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

where BaseException, UnauthorizedException and BarequestException are respectively:

```
public abstract class BaseException extends WebApplicationException
{
    private Response r;

    public BaseException(Response response)
    {
        r = response;
    }

    public Response getResponse()
    {
        return r;
    }
}

public class UnauthorizedException extends BaseException
{
    public UnauthorizedException(Response response)
    {
        super(response);
    }
}

public class BadrequestException extends BaseException
{
    public BadrequestException(Response response)
    {
        super(response);
    }
}
```

So, all works fine until i handle jackson exceptions...In fact i defined another exception mapper ,similar to the first one, to handle all the exception generated by jackson (like for example JsonMappingException) but doesn't work. I report you the error i obtain by my application:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "serverr" (Class controller.server.control.response.GetServerDetailsResponse), not marked as ignorable
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@701d7463; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: controller.server.control.response.GetServerDetailsResponse["serverr"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:181)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
```

My first question is: it may be that the two classes go in conflict, that is there aren't two exception mappers in the same project? The second question is: how can i resolve this issue?
I hope i was clear and thanks you in advance for your help!

Hi, i just read a post in which it's presented the same problem that i have; i report you the link of the question: [Jersey: Returning 400 error instead of 500 when given invalid request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844654/jersey-returning-400-error-instead-of-500-when-given-invalid-request-body) .
As first thing i try the code written in the first answer of the post but with the same result as before: i always obtain 500 error code instead of 400 when i knowingly insert an error in the request body. 
I also try to put *@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)* above the class that deals with intercept the request body, but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have not registered your ExceptionMapper into the application runtime loading class provider.
Try to add the mapper class to it with the following code:

```
   @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
    public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
       public MyApplication() {
           packages("controller");
           register(JacksonFeature.class);
           register(ClientExceptionMapper.class);          
       }
    }
```

Hope it could be helpful :)