# How to return custom response on javax.json.bind.JsonbException (Helidon project)

Tags: java, jax-rs, helidon

I'm trying to return a custom http response(400 bad request) instead of http 500 server error when json payload is not valid.
The problem is that when I use `javax.json.bind.JsonbException` as exception type in `ExceptionMapper<T>` it's not able to catch it, but I can catch the more generic `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException`.
It is obvious that the `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException` is caused by `javax.json.bind.JsonbException` as stack trace is showing:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:885)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:684)
    at io.helidon.webserver.jersey.JerseySupport$JerseyHandler.lambda$doAccept$4(JerseySupport.java:326)
    at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:117)
    at io.helidon.common.context.ContextAwareExecutorImpl.lambda$wrap$7(ContextAwareExecutorImpl.java:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'date' because of: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 2022-03-31T10:37:23.005Z[UTC]x. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:84)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error parsing class java.util.Date from value: 2022-03-31T10:37:23.005Z[UTC]x. Check your @JsonbDateFormat has all time units for class java.util.Date type, or consider using org.eclipse.yasson.YassonConfig#ZERO_TIME_PARSE_DEFAULTING.
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:94)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-03-31T10:37:23.005Z[UTC]x' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 29
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseWithOrWithoutZone(DateTypeDeserializer.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.java:72)
    ... 42 more
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to catch the `javax.json.bind.JsonbException`?

I am using Helidon-MP 2.4.2.

Reproduce:

1. create a quick start of Helidon-MP [Link](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/02_quickstart)
2. add a post method on greeting resource

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void add(MyClass cal){
        System.out.println(cal.getDate());
    }
```

```
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public MyClass(String name, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public MyClass() {
    }
    
}
```

3.send a post request with invalid json date.
valid payoad:

```
{
    "name": "testg",
    "date": "2022-03-31T10:37:23.005Z[UTC]"
}
```

invalid (date) payload:

```
{
    "name": "testg",
    "date": "2022-03-31T10:37:23.005Z[UTC]XXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: It's just [how the provider is implemented](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/media/json-binding/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jsonb/internal/JsonBindingProvider.java). It explicitly throws a ProcessingException (wrapping the the JSON exception). So it wouldn't be possible to catch the JSON exception in an ExceptionMapper. If you used Jackson, you could get the behavior you want

Answer (score 0):

I've been working in similar trouble, and i got this solution following this one previous solution ([Jersey: Returning 400 error instead of 500 when given invalid request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844654/jersey-returning-400-error-instead-of-500-when-given-invalid-request-body)).

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MapperException;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE;
@Provider
public class InvalidDataMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonbException>         {
@Override
public Response toResponse(JsonbException arg0) {
    if (arg0.getCause() instanceof MapperException) {
        MapperException exception = (MapperException) arg0.getCause();
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = null;
        if (exception.getCause() instanceof DateTimeParseException) {
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(CustomCodesAndMessages.CODE_ERROR_FORMAT_DATE, exception.getMessage());
        }
        if (exception.getCause() instanceof NumberFormatException) {
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(CustomCodesAndMessages.CODE_ERROR_FORMATO_NUMERIC, exception.getMessage());
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).type(APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).entity(errorMessage).build();
    }
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
  }
}
```

And ErrorMessage is

```
package fif.tech.utiles;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.Nullable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ErrorMessage {
private final int code;
private final String message;
private final String details;
public ErrorMessage(String message) {
    this(500, message);
}
public ErrorMessage(int code, String message) {
    this(code, message, null);
}
@JsonCreator
public ErrorMessage(@JsonProperty("code") int code,     @JsonProperty("message") String message,
                    @Nullable @JsonProperty("details") String details) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
}
@JsonProperty("code")
public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

@JsonProperty("message")
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

@JsonProperty("details")
@Nullable
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((obj == null) || (getClass() != obj.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }

    final ErrorMessage other = (ErrorMessage) obj;
    return Objects.equals(code, other.code)
            && Objects.equals(message, other.message)
            && Objects.equals(details, other.details);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(code, message, details);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ErrorMessage{code=" + code + ", message='" + message + "', details='" + details + "'}";
 }
}
```

Now i'm trying to catch the detailed field that produce the exception, but i think that is a enough solution.